# variable error in python, not taking variable

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def main_func():
dice_num = get_random_dice()

for item in dice_list:
    if dice_num == item:
        dice1 = PhotoImage(file='./img/1.png')
        dice2 = PhotoImage(file='./img/2.png')
        dice3 = PhotoImage(file='./img/3.png')
        dice4 = PhotoImage(file='./img/4.png')
        dice5 = PhotoImage(file='./img/5.png')
        dice6 = PhotoImage(file='./img/6.png')

        dice_val.config(text=item)
        dice_img_lable.config(image=f'dice{item}')
        dice_img_lable.image = f'dice{item}'
```

in this function when I want to change the image in the label according to the num that comes, but an error is coming it is showing that

> File "C:\Users\B.M.C\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1627, in _configure
> self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
> _tkinter.TclError: image "dice4" doesn't exist

please tell me how to solve this error

Comment: What is `dice_val`?  What is `dice_img_lable`?  Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I would also recommed working on the title of th question a bit, since it seems to have more to do with loading images in Tkinter.

Comment: no its just a part of a programme i am working on

Comment: `f'dice{item}'`returns a string not a reference to your dicex variables

Comment: how can i fix it

Comment: What is `dice_list`?  Do you need a loop here?  You can just write `dice_img_lable.config(image=PhotoImage(file=f'./img{dice_num}.png'))` or something like that.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to acces a variable by its name. A string and a variable are different things. Here's the improved version of your code:

```
def main_func():
    dice_num = get_random_dice()

    dice1 = PhotoImage(file='./img/1.png')
    dice2 = PhotoImage(file='./img/2.png')
    dice3 = PhotoImage(file='./img/3.png')
    dice4 = PhotoImage(file='./img/4.png')
    dice5 = PhotoImage(file='./img/5.png')
    dice6 = PhotoImage(file='./img/6.png')

    dice_images = [dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, dice6]

    for n, item in enumerate(dice_list):
        if dice_num == n:
            dice_val.config(text=f'dice{n}')
            dice_img_lable.config(image=dice_images[item-1])
            dice_img_lable.image = dice_images[item-1]
```

You can even skip the if statement altogether.
Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't even notice that there is something wrong

Comment: Also the last line of the code, I dont think it will keep a reference to the image, as its a string, its better to say `dice_img_lable.image = dice_images[item-1]`

Comment: I dont think that will work, it might be a mistake by the OP as well. Not sure.

Comment: There's one more thing.`item` is not an integer it seems while dice_num is. Thus...

Comment: Without more information its hard to say anything, so ya..